# Laravel error inserting data into table from another table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to insert into product table a form data and one field which i pulled from another table called Purchase by using the code below

```
 Product::create([
            'purchase_id'=>$request->product,
            'price'=>$price,
            'discount'=>$request->discount,
            'description'=>$request->description,
            'purchase_purchaseprice' => Purchase::where('id',$request->product)->get('price'),
        ]);
```

But i get this error message, and i think the issue is this `[{"price":"25.00"}]`but i failed to format the query to insert only 25.00 amount, Please help ?

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime
> format: 1366 Incorrect decimal value: '[{"price":"25.00"}]' for column
> `laravel`.`products`.`purchase_purchaseprice` at row 1 (SQL: insert
> into `products` (`purchase_id`, `price`, `discount`, `description`,
> `purchase_purchaseprice`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (262,
> 4000, 0, ?, [{"price":"25.00"}], 2021-11-19 18:25:59, 2021-11-19
> 18:25:59))

Here is the table schema

```
+------------------------+------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                  | Type                   | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------------+------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                     | bigint(20) unsigned    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| purchase_id            | bigint(20) unsigned    | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| price                  | decimal(15,2) unsigned | NO   |     | 0.00    |                |
| discount               | decimal(15,2) unsigned | NO   |     | 0.00    |                |
| description            | text                   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| deleted_at             | timestamp              | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at             | timestamp              | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at             | timestamp              | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| purchase_purchaseprice | decimal(15,2) unsigned | NO   |     | 0.00    |                |
+------------------------+------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: Can you double-check and show your table schema? Apparently `purchase_purchaseprice` is set to be a datetime column

Comment: @aynber i updated the question with the table schema

Answer (score 0):

look like you have $price as json not as a simple decimal, so you have to decode it ...

another issue, you are assigning an array to purchase_purchaseprice' ...
to fix this:

```
 Product::create([
            'purchase_id'=>$request->product,
            'price'=>json_decode($price,true)[0]['price'],
            'discount'=>$request->discount,
            'description'=>$request->description,
            'purchase_purchaseprice' => Purchase::find($request->product)->price,
        ]);
```

Comment: Thanks alot , it is working now